# Is a SOQL query with FOR UPDATE enough to safely delete a record?

Tags: soql, locking

I have a scenario where an external system is calling the Salesforce API, causing a trigger to run. That trigger needs to delete `EmailMessage` records where the `RelatedTo` field is an Account.

We're getting `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` errors when the external system's API calls overlap and the trigger attempts to delete multiple emails on the same `Account` at the same time.

This is totally understandable based on how [record-locking works](https://d259t2jj6zp7qm.cloudfront.net/images/20210727114613/SF_Record-Locking-Cheatsheet_web-1.pdf). `RelatedTo` is either a required lookup or a Master-Detail so deleting the `EmailMessage` would require a lock on the related `Account`.

I tried to solve the problem by adding `FOR UPDATE` to the query in the trigger where it fetches the `EmailMessage` records.

But, we still observe `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` as a `DmlException` (if it were a `QueryException`, then that might be due to the 10-second limit timing out).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation you're looking for is [Avoiding Deadlocks](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_deadlocks.htm).

> As a developer, use care when locking rows to ensure that you are not introducing deadlocks. Verify that you are using standard deadlock avoidance techniques by accessing tables and rows in the same order from all locations in an application.

To avoid problems, you must always lock any parent records before child records. While the documentation doesn't have much to say about this beyond this one page, it's incredibly important. If you want to update a Contact, lock the Account. If you want to update an Opportunity, lock the Account. Etc, etc.

If you don't lock the parent record explicitly, then Apex:

> First locks sObject parent records, then children.
>
> Locks sObject records in order of ID when multiple records of the same type are being edited.

Relying on this automatic locking mechanism is fine for most types of objects, as they are usually not very "busy" in most orgs, but Account is one object you should almost always use locking statements on, simply because they must be locked anyways for many of the standard CRM objects.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox. I don't find that documentation very satisfactory, but I think you're right that it's the best there is for this.

Comment: @sfdcfox - As always, many thanks for your insights. To lock the parent record explicitly, is it possible to edit and/or use the same SOQL statement for the child record to achieve this or would I need to execute an additional SOQL statement for the parent record? If the latter is the case, would performing a DML operation on the queried child record automatically release the lock on the queried parent record or would I have to explicitly perform a DML operation on the queried parent record also to release the lock on it?

Comment: @user73893 See [FOR UPDATE](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.236.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_for_update.htm). The first answer is unclear, though I believe you do need separate queries for each lock (parents then children). Try to optimize so you only have to lock the parents once per transaction. Locks are only released when (a) a callout occurs, or (b) the transaction finalizes. Performing a DML locks all records for the rest of the transaction, as no callouts are allowed after DML.

Answer (score 3):

Looking again at the locking documents (and reading the actual words `FOR UPDATE`), it says that a query with `FOR UPDATE` "Locks all records retrieved in `SELECT`
statement that uses `FOR UPDATE`." It does not say that it locks any records related to those returned by the query.

So, if I lock the `EmailMessage`, I should not expect it to lock the related `Account`. I'm locking as if I want to **update** the record. When I delete the `EmailMessage`, it tries to lock the `Account` and fails.

So, what I'd really need is a SOQL clause like `FOR DELETE`. Or I'd need to do an extra SOQL on the `RelatedToId`s to explicitly lock the Accounts.

So locking `FOR UPDATE` locks the record as if you want to update it. It's not enough for a delete.

It also doesn't appear to take into account something like Roll-Up summaries. Perhaps you could lock a record with a Roll-Up summary `FOR UPDATE` and still get an `UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW` error if you attempt to update it.